# Can the Whatsapp icon appear and disappear from someone's contact?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have this problem of my boyfriend's whatsapp icon appearing and disappearing on his contact. It doesn't seem honest to me that he says that he doesn't have whatsapp when I clearly see that during his working hours or at times he is not with me the icon is not there but on the afternoons or on weekends the icon dissapears. Is this possible?

Comment: It's some problem with the WhatsApp app I guess. I too face the issues sometimes. We have to wait till a proper update is released.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah the contact apps have contact accounts. You can click options button and select contacts to display. Unmark WhatsApp as a contact source and it won't show up in contacts. Tried for my CM13 on Wileyfox Spark and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

The WhatsApp icon that appears in your contacts app when viewing his contact details, shows that he has WhatsApp.[image]

This screenshot shows that the contact has WhatsApp, telegram, and the number is saved to my Google account.

There are two possibilities as to why this icon appears and disappears at times.

It's possible that he deletes his WhatsApp account and reactivates it every time (very unlikely that someone would go thru the pain every few days, but still possible)

The other possibility is that your WhatsApp app is a little unstable and therefore it's not sure if the number is still part of WhatsApp, or not.

I would suggest you simply press on the WhatsApp icon the next time you see it, and send him a WhatsApp message, that way you'll know for sure that he has it.